# How to load content in Blazored texteditor

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly, mudblazor

I am using Blazor Text Editor from the source below.

Source - https://github.com/Blazored/TextEditor

I have a table with the set of content and in the last column, I have an action button, if I click the button mud-drawer will open, and there I have blazored text editor. I want to load my content(particular column values) there. I used bind-Values but it's not working. I don't know how to pull this.

This is what I have tried so far.

```
<MudTable Items="@items" 
      Some table related stuff here  
<RowTemplate>
    <MudTd DataLabel="Control Category">@context.ControlCategory</MudTd>
    <MudTd DataLabel="Question">@context.AsessmentQuestion</MudTd>
    <MudTd DataLabel="Question Tooltip">@context.AssessmentQuestionToolTip</MudTd>
    <MudTd DataLabel="Risk Weightage">@context.RiskWeightage</MudTd>
    <MudTd DataLabel="Action">
        @*@{
            body = @context.AsessmentQuestion;
        }*@
        <MudButton Variant="Variant.Filled" Color="Color.Secondary" OnClick="@(() => OpenDrawer(Anchor.Right))">Action</MudButton>      
    </MudTd>
</RowTemplate> 
</MudTable>

<MudDrawer @bind-Open="@open" DisableOverlay="true" Width="550px" Height="auto" Anchor="@anchor" Elevation="0" Variant="@DrawerVariant.Responsive">  
<MudNavMenu >
    <MudNavLink Match="NavLinkMatch.All"> 
        <BlazoredTextEditor @ref="@QuillHtml">
            <ToolbarContent>
                some toolbar content here
            </ToolbarContent>           
            <EditorContent >
                @((MarkupString)infoBlock.Description)
                @*@bind-Value="@body"*@
                @*@((MarkupString) body)*@
                
            </EditorContent>
        </BlazoredTextEditor>
        <br />
        <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="GetHTML">Get HTML</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary"@onclick="SetHTML">Set HTML</button>
        @*<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="GetEditorContent">Get Content</button>*@
        <br />
        <div>
            <br />
            @((MarkupString)QuillHTMLContent)
            @QuillHTMLContent
        </div>
    </MudNavLink>
</MudNavMenu>
</MudDrawer>

@code {
//BlazoredTextEditor QuillHtml;
BlazoredTextEditor QuillNative;
BlazoredTextEditor QuillReadOnly;
string QuillHTMLContent;
string QuillContent;
string QuillReadOnlyContent =
    @"<span><b>Read Only</b> <u>Content</u></span>";
private string body = "";
[Parameter] public EventCallback OnValidSubmit { get; set; }
BlazoredTextEditor QuillHtml = new BlazoredTextEditor();

private async Task LocalOnValidSubmit()
{
    infoBlock.Description = await this.QuillHtml.GetHTML();
    await OnValidSubmit.InvokeAsync(this);//to call event handler passed by parent after the HTML prepared for main bound class
}
public async void GetHTML()
{
    QuillHTMLContent = await this.QuillHtml.GetHTML();
    StateHasChanged();
}
public async void SetHTML()
{
    string QuillContent =
        @"<a href='http://BlazorHelpWebsite.com/'>" +
        "<img src='images/BlazorHelpWebsite.gif' /></a>";

    await this.QuillHtml.LoadHTMLContent(QuillContent);
    StateHasChanged();
}
//public async Task GetEditorContent()
//{
//    EditorHTMLContent = "";
//    EditorContent = await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<string>(
//        "QuillFunctions.getQuillContent", divEditorElement);
//     = await this.QuillNative.GetHTML();
//}
protected async Task clickdb()
{
    try
    {
        var item = await riskservice.GetItems();
        items = item.ToList();
        if (items.Count > 0)
        {
            body = items[0].AsessmentQuestion;
        }
        StateHasChanged();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        snackBar.Add($"An error occurred: {ex.Message}", Severity.Error);
    }
} // some mudtable related codes...
```

}

i want > @context.AsessmentQuestion  in blazored text editor box. how to pull this?
Thanks

Comment: Can you please remove all the unnecessary (for this question) commented out code and provide the class models.